# @CurrentSecurityContext always inject null in mockMvc integration tests?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test, spring-boot-test, spring-security-rest

I am using the spring security annotation @CurrentSecurityContext to inject the authentication object. This works well when the application is running, but in a @SpringBootTest it always injects null, even when using @WithMockUser.

When adding breakpoints, the Authentication object in the SpringSecurityContext is correctly filled with a mock user principal, but the @CurrentSecurityContext resolver, namely: CurrentSecurityContextArgumentResolver is never used, it won't stop at any breakpoint (constructor, or resolver method) in this class.

I am using spring boot:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
```

And use mockMvc to perform a test:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
void activate_NotActivatedYet() {
  ....
  var result = mockMvc.perform(put(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(content)
        .characterEncoding(CHAR_ENCODING))
    .andDo(print())
    .andDo(result -> flushIfNeeded())
    .andDo(result -> entityManager.clear());
 .....
}
```

And my rest endpoint:

```
@PutMapping("/{code}/activate")
public ResponseEntity<PromoCodeRestDto> activate(@CurrentSecurityContext Authentication authentication,
                                                 @PathVariable String code) {
    log.info("Requesting to activate the promo code with code [{}]", code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your argument type is wrong, instead of `Authentication` you should use `SecurityContext`. The javadoc for the `@CurrentSecurityContext` says:

> Annotation that is used to resolve the org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext as a method argument.

Otherwise, if you just want the `Authentication` you don't need any annotation to resolve it. If you want the `Principal` of the authentication, you can use the `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` annotation.

Comment: Why is it wrong? It works well, only not during testing, why?